# NEXT-AUTH URI MISMATCH after i uploaded my project to vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel

I built a next.Js application using next-auth and google provider as authentication.After hosting the application on vercel. The authentication failed and always get uri-mistmatch when ever i tried to sign in .
I am not using a custom domain. I am using vercel auto generated domain name ....

this the link ot the app. https://nirvana-delta.vercel.app. This is the base .
I also updated thre authorized on google cloud console ... but still get uri-mismatch..
I dont know if it because , vercel always create a new url when you update your source code .